# How to evaluate a limit here?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have a certain limit to evaluate: $\lim_{x\to  0}\frac{4^x-1}{\ln{(7x+1)}}$

Here are the steps I've followed:

1. suppose $4^x-1$ is t. This means that $t\to0$. This also means that $x=\log_4(t+1)$
2. My limit is now: $\lim_{t\to  0}\frac{t}{\ln(7log_4(t+1) + 1)}$
3. Now $\ln(log_4(t+1) +1)$ is equal to $log_4(t+1)$ beacuse the $ln$ function is also $\to0$
4. This, i suppose, leaves us with the following limit: $\lim_{t\to  0}\frac{t}{7log_4(t+1)}$

At my last step I got really confused. Where else can we go from here? Every time I find myself with an indermediate form of [$\frac{0}{0}$].

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What about L'Hospital?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) is your friend:

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4^x-1}{\ln{(7x+1)}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4^x\ln(4)}{\frac{7}{7x+1}}=\frac{\ln(4)}{7}$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

By standard limit we have that

$$\frac{4^x-1}{\ln{(7x+1)}}=\frac{\ln 4}7 \cdot \frac{e^{x\ln 4}-1}{x\ln 4}\cdot \frac{7x}{\ln{(7x+1)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply and divide by $x$. Then use,

> $$\lim_{x\to 0 } \frac{a^x-1}{x} = \ln(a)\\\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(7x+1)}{x} = 7\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(7x+1)}{7x} = 7$$

Answer (score 1):

Numerator :

$4^x-1= e^{x\log 4}-1=$

$x\log 4 +O(x^2);$

Denominator:

$\log (1+7x)=7x +O(x^2);$

Finally

$\dfrac{4^x-1}{\log (1+7x)}= \dfrac{\log 4 +O(x)} {7+O(x)}.$